# What is the lowest SDK version that react native will support?

Tags: react-native

Will react native support at least version 15 of the SDK? If not, how can I use react native apps on Android 4.0?

My app users may use old phones for now (health & medicine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native supports API 16 and newer. If you need API 15 you can't use React Native.

> Supported operating systems are >= Android 4.1 (API 16) and >= iOS 7.0.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/README.md

Only about 4.3% of android users are on devices running 4.0.x or older.
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Do you know how to set this?